# T-SQL IF statement embedded in a sum() function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm attempting to convert a MySQL query to a T-SQL query and the IF statement that's enclosed within a SUM statement is tripping me up. Any suggestions?

```
SELECT
    CMTS_RQ.[Dated],
    CMTS_RQ.CMTS_Name,
    Count(CMTS_RQ.CMTS_Name) AS emat_count,
    Sum(if(CMTS_RQ.US_Pwr>=37 and CMTS_RQ.US_Pwr<=49)) AS us_pwr_good
FROM
    CMTS_RQ
GROUP BY
    CMTS_RQ.CMTS_Name,
    CMTS_RQ.[Dated]
```

But I get an error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'if'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

T-SQL doesn't have a "inline" `IF` statement - use a `CASE` instead:

```
SELECT
    CMTS_RQ.[Dated],
    CMTS_RQ.CMTS_Name,
    Count(CMTS_RQ.CMTS_Name) AS emat_count,
    Sum(CASE 
           WHEN CMTS_RQ.US_Pwr >=37 AND CMTS_RQ.US_Pwr <= 49 
             THEN 1
             ELSE 0 
        END) AS us_pwr_good
FROM
    CMTS_RQ
GROUP BY
    CMTS_RQ.CMTS_Name,
    CMTS_RQ.[Dated]
```

So if the value of `CMTS_RQ.US_Pwr` is `>= 37 AND <= 49` then add 1 to the `SUM` - otherwise 0. Does that give you what you're looking for?

In SQL Server **2012** and newer, you can use the new [`IIF` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx):

```
SUM(IIF(CMTS_RQ.US_Pwr >= 37 AND CMTS_RQ.US_Pwr <= 49, 1, 0)) AS us_pwr_good
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight, that points me in the right direction.