# Getting the difference of the two same dates MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys here is my coode:

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(L_End, L_Start)), L_Start,L_End
        FROM leave_table 
        where ID_No = '9283158370' and L_Status = 'Approve' and L_Type ='Sick'
```

That is working but my dilemma is what if the start and end date are the same, like for example start date is 2015-03-10 and end date is also 2015-03-10. If I query that in the DATEDIFF function the difference is 0. What I would like to is date diff is equal to **1**. Since It the start and the end date is 1 day.

Comment: have a look here, I guess. Construct a conditional in your SUM(); http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16528906/t-sql-if-statement-embedded-in-a-sum-function or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732036/mysql-sum-query-with-if-condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need something like:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(L_End, L_Start) = '0' THEN 1 ELSE DATEDIFF(L_End, L_Start) END) as summed_column, L_Start,L_End
    FROM leave_table 
    where ID_No = '9283158370' and L_Status = 'Approve' and L_Type ='Sick'
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know I could do that in mysql. Again thank you soo much!